# How to import and export JBPM 6.5 Repositories

Tags: import, repository, export, jbpm

I'd like to ask you if you know how to export and import JBPM projects between different Kie Workbenches. I am using JBPM 6.5
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using Git is probably the only sound way. Following this sequence, it's possible to put the project into a git repository and later import it to some other instance.

On the machine with the jBPM server:

1. Init new local git repo in some folder

   git init
2. Add the jBPM server repo remote

   git remote add business-central ssh://user_name@localhost:8001/space_name/project_name
3. Pull the server repo to your local repo

   git pull business-central master

Done. Now you can push your local git repo to wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If all projects are in one repository, you can simply clone your repository or pull or push to 
ssh://@localhost:8001/

port 8001 is the default, you should change according to your setting.

here is how to clone:
[image]

Alternatively, copy your org.guvnor.m2repo.dir to the destination you want.
https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/wb.Workbench.html#wb.workbenchData

I personally prefer option 1 as it is much easier to me.

Comment: How do I use git with the address you provided?

Comment: I actually don't work with JBPM anylonger as I have moved to another company. However, as far as I remember, I used "git clone"