# Import and Export JBPM 7.59 Processes

Tags: jboss, jbpm, kie, drools-kie-server, kie-server

Can anyone please help me here to understand that how can I export all processes of JBPM 7.59 in one folder? or How can I clone a repository?

So far what I did is using the below methodology to get the process from JBPM

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56167353/13864904

but again this will help me to get a single process and I have more than 100 processes develop on JBPM so how can I export all of them at once?

I have also did the below methodology but didn't find any luck here either,

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/249463

here swiderski.maciej has said to clone the repo but when I did this it give me an error that, git doesn't find the repository.

I used this command **git clone ssh://wbadmin@localhost:8001/(myspace name here)**

but this didn't work either maybe I'm giving the wrong URL (someone can help me here)

My main goal is that I want to export all processes which I have develop on JBPM and commit it on some external GIT repository but by above method it is very difficult for me to pull each process individually and then import it into another environment one by one.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

In your business central project setting you will get the URL so that you can clone it like ssh://HOST_NAME:8080/REPOSITORY_NAME.

You can also use the git hook[1] , it will integrate your jbpm project to your github.

https://porcelli.me/rhba/business-central/git/setup/githook/2018/11/05/business-central-git-setup-hook.html

Comment: Thank you @Amit for ur reply. 
I didn't get this  command **ssh://HOST_NAME:8080/REPOSITORY_NAME**, from where I can get **REPOSITORY_NAME**? or by **REPOSITORY_NAME** you mean **Space** Name?
Actually the full path would be **ssh://HOST_NAME:8080/SPACE_NAME/PROCESS_NAME** so with this I will only pull a single process at a time. 
What if I want to fetch all processes at once? I have more than 100 processes.

Comment: Go to in your project setting option in business central where you will get the complete URL to clone your project which contains all the jbpm assests,

Comment: Thanks, but that url is for one process how can I export all processes which I have developed in my space? 
The url in project setting is this: **ssh://localhost:8001/MySpace/SampleProcess** which export only Sample Process I have to export all processes which is in **MySpace** which contained 100 of processes.

Comment: I think you have multiple projects in my space and you want to export all the projects which contains the processes. First of all you can export the project one by one not the complete my space. Please let me know if you have 100 process in single project or in different project.  You can export the project using this url ssh://abc@localhost:8001/MySpace/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME